# How to write excel formula for data validation between range of numbers?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am not familiar with much excel Syntax and features. But I am trying to add data validations for few cells. So, for a cell if the value entered is between 0 - 100, it should allow to enter the number, if its not between 0-100 it should enter **No**.

Basically if the entered value is not a numeric number it should allow them to write **NO**

SO far i managed to get this logic: Lets say I am using cell A1
`IF(AND(A1>0,A1<100),"YES","NO")`

The problem with this logic is If the condition is satisfied , this will write yes but I want them to write the number, not **YES**.

Please ask if this doesn't make much sense?Thanks :)

Comment: A guess: `=OR(AND(A1>0,A1<100),A1="NO")`.

Answer (score 1):

So using Data Validation:

[image]

Tested with wrong numbers:
[image]

And you can put the lim its on the sheet as so:
[image]

BUT has to have absolute referencing to cells C2 & C3